# How to set PreferenceFragment as tab's fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-preferences

I want to use preferenceFragment. I  have a tabbed activity and in tabbed activity in one fragment I want to show all the preferences. So this fragment is support fragment of v4 i.e android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

How can I set preferenceFragment here?

I tried this way :

```
   public class PreferencesFrag extends PreferenceFragment {



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_preferences, container, false);
    }

}
```

But this shows error in pager's adapter when I try to call the fragment:

Adapter:

```
   public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    CharSequence Titles[];
    int NumbOfTabs;

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, CharSequence mTitles[], int mNumbOfTabsumb) {
        super(fm);
        this.Titles = mTitles;
        this.NumbOfTabs = mNumbOfTabsumb;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index) {

        switch (index) {
            case 0:
                return new BasicInformationFragment();
            case 1:
                return new PersonalDetailsFragment();
            case 2:
                return new PreferencesFrag();
            case 3:
                return new InviteFriendsFagment();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return Titles[position];
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NumbOfTabs;
    }
}
```

EDIT:

I had tried this way to replace fragment but it dose not replace it the tab dose not move ahead.

```
     PreferencesFrag fragment2 = new PreferencesFrag();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment1, fragment2);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

It shows error that wrong second type of argument required v4.app.fragement found fragments.PreferenceFragment.

Shows error on preference frag.
How can I do this?
Thank you..

Comment: What error does it show?

Comment: post your error log too

Comment: It shows error ncompatible types, required v4.app.fragment found framents.PreferencesFragment.

Comment: i have done it but i don't have the code currently

Comment: how to solve this but, it gives error on second argument. @ankitagrawal

Answer (score 0):

Use a `nestedFragment` load a dummy `fragment` in `TabAdapter` and in that fragment replace it with a `PreferenceFragment` android

Comment: how to replace preference fragment from fragment? @ankit agrawal

Comment: use getsupportfragmentmanager.begintransaction.replace(r.id.container,your fragment).commit();